# Что за ошибка phpStorm и как ее исправить?

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver

Начала выскакивать вот такая ошибка в phpStorm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую open server, когда хочу увидеть результат своего кода в браузере, появляется ошибка 502

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алиасы правильно прописаны - проверял. Что это может быть? Раньше все четко работало

Comment: Вообще-то таам ссылка в сообщении.

Comment: это я вижу. Я не понимаю, phpstorm не может найти интрпретатор или что? Как это исправить?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/401806 может поможет

Comment: Пробовали на ссылку нажать? Должно появиться окно по [типу такого](http://croper.ru/images/20170521RWWT269DmAoKcfAM_x1fcR_large.png?49758)

Comment: @KitScribe конечно. Предложило указать путь в интерпретатору в open server, хотя раньше этой ошибки никогда не было

Comment: @Евгений это не ошибка. Такое окно появляется либо когда IDE не видит интерпретатор, либо когда их несколько. И `phpStorm` просто говорит: "Чувак, я не знаю какой мне использовать, настрой меня"

Comment: Вы пытаетесь просмотреть страницу не через OpenServer, а через сервер, интегрированный в PHP. PhpStorm нужен путь к php-интерпретатору, чтобы корректно отобразить страницу

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, Вы пытаетесь открыть Вашу страничку на вебсервере,  встроенном в PHPStorm (`http://localhost:63342`). Этот сервер не умеет сам исполнять PHP, нужно указать путь к PHP интерпретатору в `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`, `CLI Interpreter:`